# Finite measure subset of (possibly) infinite measure regarding $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

Suppose (X, $\mathcal{M}$, $\mu$) is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and let $g\in L^\infty(\mu)$. Can we always consider that for sets of the form ($\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small)

$$
A_{\epsilon} = \{x \in X: |g(x)|\geq ||g||_{\infty} - \epsilon > 0 \}
$$

there exists a measurable subset $B\subset A_{\epsilon}$ such that $0<\mu(B)<+\infty$? Why or why not? I would need this result in order to prove some results for my measure theory class. Given the definition of the L infinity norm, it is clear to me that $\mu(A_{\epsilon})>0$, but taking for instance a constant function in an infinite measure space, I think the measure of said set could also be infinite. In this scenario, I doesn't look trivial to me that we can assume a positive and finite measure subset exists in an arbitrary measure space.

Edit: Changed (X, $\mathcal{M}$, $\mu$) from an arbitrary space to a $\sigma$-finite measure space to avoid obvious counterexamples.

Comment: This is too general. What if $\mu (A)=\infty$ for every non-empty set $A$?

Comment: You could have the measure be defined so that all measurable sets are either of measure $0$ or $\infty$, so no, such $B$ may not exist.

Comment: You would need something like a semifinite measure, which is a measure $\mu$ s.t. for any $A$ with $\mu(A) > 0$, there exists $B \subseteq A$ with $0 < \mu(B) < + \infty$. In fact, by considering indicator functions of measurable sets, the result you need is equivalent to $\mu$ being semifinite. (In practice, basically all “natural” measures one would encounter are semifinite, so this isn’t much of a restriction.)

Comment: @DavidGao thanks for pointing that out, edited to add $\sigma$-finite constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prove a more general result, namely for any $A$ with $\mu(A) > 0$, there exists $B \subseteq A$ with $0 < \mu(B) < +\infty$, assuming $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Indeed, as $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, there exists an increasing sequence of measurable sets $X_i$ s.t. $\cup_{i = 1}^\infty X_i = X$ and $\mu(X_i) < +\infty$ for all $i$. But then $A_i = A \cap X_i$ is an increasing sequence of measurable sets with $\cup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i = A$, so $\mu(A_i) \rightarrow \mu(A)$. In particular, as $\mu(A) > 0$, there exists $i$ s.t. $\mu(A_i) > 0$. We also have $\mu(A_i) \leq \mu(X_i) < +\infty$, so setting $B = A_i$ proves the claim.